# Slick Slider: How to set arrows inside and not outside?

Tags: jquery, html, slider

Hi I found slick slider to be really easy to use and decided it to use on a website i've been working on: http://smallbuildersdev.esy.es/

You can see the slider on the bottom of the page. I have just one problem. I want the arrows to be inside the slider and not outside of it (that also means that when the content slides in, it slides from an invisible hard edge). Is there a way to put the arrows inside so i can occupy the full width of the page (so no hard edges when sliding will be visible)? Here is the link to slick slider: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

If you also look at the slick slider webpage the left/right arrows are outside the slider.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you can simply change the CSS style.

```
.slick-prev {
    left: 100px;
    background: red; /*to notice it, is white*/
}
.slick-next {
    right: 100px;
    background: red; /*to notice it, is white*/
}
```

Comment: Using percentage (2% ~ 3%) works great on responsible designs.

Comment: use       z-index: 10; if you cannot see the arrows

Answer (score 25):

add z-index: 1 to the answer by UberKaeL to force prev-arrow display on top of image

```
.slick-prev {
  left: 100px;
  background: red; /*to notice it, is white*/
  z-index: 1;
}
.slick-next {
  right: 100px;
  background: red; /*to notice it, is white*/
}
```

Comment: None of these answers are responsive at all. You cannot resize the window and have them display properly doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the accepted answer and found my css was not taking effect.  I ended up using !Important to have the arrow become visible...

```
.slick-prev {
    left: 100px !important;
    background-color: red  !important; /*to notice it, is white*/
}
.slick-next {
    right: 100px !important;
    background-color: red  !important; /*to notice it, is white*/
}
```

Comment: I suspect this is because you are adding your overridden CSS before the default slick CSS is added to the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
.yourclass{
  .slick-prev {
    left: 100px;
    background: white;
  }
  .slick-next {
    right: 100px;
    background: white;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more detail to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to add !important to your stylesheet, add the .slick-arrow class to your css.

```
.slick-arrow.slick-prev {
  left: 100px;
  background: red; /*to notice it, is white*/
  z-index: 1;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-next {
  right: 100px;
  background: red; /*to notice it, is white*/
}
```